# How to create Http Response with Dart

Tags: rest, dart, httpserver

I was trying to follow along with one of the [Dart HttpServer examples](https://github.com/dart-lang/route) from GitHub, and, while it does show how to create and handle routes, I'm still at a loss on how to produce and send an `HttpResponce` in response to a specific url being requested.

For example, while working with WebAPI, I would have an Api Controller, in which I could explicitly define an action for GET, PUT, DELETE and POST verbs, and return an appropriate `HttpResponse` with a resource from each such method.

Does anyone know how this typical CRUD business is done using Dart as an Http server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you receive a `HttpRequest` you need to use the `response` attribute to answer.

```dart
void sendOk(HttpRequest request, [content]) {
  request.response
    ..statusCode = HttpStatus.OK
    ..write(content)
    ..close()
    ;
}
```